# Fetched data from firebase sometimes does not get added to cell despite having been fetched before

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I fetch data from firebase in the following way :

```
fetchUsers (gets UIDs of people the current user follows)
  -for each user fetch his posts
     -for this user fetch his personal user-data (like profile image and username)
```

**Note**: I reload data after calling the *"for each user fetch his posts"* and inside of that for each post.

Now here is the weird part. Inside of the method shown below, which is called when querying firebase for the necessary data, there are print statements showing the data. When looking at this data It is always there just as needed (profile image URL as well as the username ect.)

```
    func addUserDataToObject(userObj: User, snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    if (snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as! String) != "" {
        userObj.profileImageUrlString = "\(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImage").value as! String)"
        userObj.fullName = "\(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "fullName").value as! String)"
        userObj.username = "\(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as! String)"
        print("\(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImage").value as! String)", " this was wireed")
    } else {
        print("the username was nil!")
    }
}
```

However when I then try and use that data in the collectionView methods it does not exist:
I print:

```
                print(postArray[indexPath.item].user.username, " This is supposed to be the username")
            print(postArray[indexPath.item].user.profileImageUrlString!, " This is supposed to be the URL")
            print(date, " This is supposed to be the date")
```

All of which will "randomly" print empty strings. Sometimes I should note they do work. I have found that consistently the first cell item works perfectly but the other 2 do not.

**Why is this happening and how do I fix it?**

### **Update:**

Here is some of the requested code:

```
    func fetchAllUserFirstPostMedia(user: String) {
    print("2344 fetch called 32424243242")

    let databaseN = Database.database().reference()

    databaseN.child("Posts").child(user).observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in

        guard snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] != nil else { return print("\(snapshot.value) <-- this is snapshot.value in return statement") }

        let userUID = user
        if user == userUID {

            guard let postDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] else { return }

            for anyPosts in postDictionary {
                print("inside the anyPosts")//will print as many times as there are posts.

                let currentPost = Post()

                let userObj = User(theuserID: userUID)
                self.retrieveUsersInfo(userObj: userObj)
                print(userObj.profileImageUrlString, " This is teh uirl for prof image")//this is Always empty (even though at leaased the first value has an image dysplayed and all seem to ahve had one when in the retriveUsersInfo() method)
              ...
```

### **Update2:**

I have found that the problem only happens to the middle 2 items (this is always true: -> index 1 and 2 always has the problem no matter what n may be) in the collection view (if it has 4 items. More items leads to only the items 1 and 2 having the problem)

Comment: Hi.. can you share the code where you are adding the User object in your array. 
The values are getting overridden from some other part of your code

Comment: What is the function "retrieveUsersInfo" doing?

Comment: ref.child("Users").child(UID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    
                    do {
                        self.addUserDataToObject(userObj: userObj, snapshot: snapshot)
                    }
                    
                }) @Nivrutti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `retrieveUsersInfo(userObj: User)` method is asynchronous, so the data used to populate the `collectionView` probably isn't loading in time.

Try rewriting your `retrieveUsersInfo` method as a closure and then iterate through the post dictionaries once your user's info has been found (I don't know what you're doing with the `anyPosts` objects you loop through, but here's what I have):

```
func fetchAllUserFirstPostMedia(user: String) {
    print("2344 fetch called 32424243242")

    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("Posts/\(user)").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        guard let postDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] else {
            print("\(snapshot.value) <-- this is snapshot.value in return statement")

            return
        }

        let userObj = User(theuserID: user)
        var posts = [Post]()

        self.retrieveUsersInfo(userObj: userObj) {
            print(userObj.profileImageUrlString)

            for anyPosts in postDictionary {
                print("inside the anyPosts")

                let currentPost = Post()

                // do whatever you need to do with anyPosts, currentPost, and userObj

                // add post object to array
                posts.append(currentPost)
            }

            print(posts) // all of your posts with the complete userObj
        }
    })
}

func retrieveUserInfo(userObj: User, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    // I'm assuming this UID object is the userObj's uid and it's coming from somewhere else?
    ref.child("Users").child(UID).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        self.addUserDataToObject(userObj: userObj, snapshot: snapshot)
        completion()
    })
}
```

A couple things I changed in your `fetchAllUserFirstPostMedia` method:

- you don't need two guard statements testing if the snapshot's value exits
- you set constant `userUID` equal to `user`, so the if statement `if user == userUID` will always succeed
- set `userObj` constant before the loop so it isn't setting each loop iteration.

Comment: My only complaint is that the speed of fetching is inconsistent. Sometimes (with the number of posts staying the same) it fetches fast other times it's slow. any idea why?

Comment: It's sometimes slower because your phone is communicating with a server, and the network speed will vary. I like using UIActivityIndicators between loading times to clean this type of stuff up

Comment: Are you sure? Becuase i ahve these fluctuations all while sitting still in teh same place. And when its slow its like 10 or 20 seconds slow

Comment: It might depend on what you’re doing with that postDictionary data after you fetch the userObj data. If not that, it might be contingent on another async call you’re making. If you post the rest of your code in that method/message me the git repository I’ll take a look.